# What is the meaning of colon in URL, followed by a wildcard character "*someparam"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I know that this question is mixture of URL knowledge and Rails-routing, but I am new to web development therefore I search for help here(not at first, I googled it but couldn't come up with understanding).

So I read that [this article](https://skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/) and some others to understand the meaning of colon 
character inside the URL. So I see that it serves as a separator for URL fragments like `scheme, username, password, port (<scheme>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>)`, but in my rails routes I find something that I don't understand:

```
get "/api/posts/public:*params", to: 'public#api_request'
```

What bugs me is this part `/public:*params` of the URL.

I thing it is a part of the `path` segment of the URL, I don't know.

Can you help me please to understand that?

Comment: Hm, looks like it should be either color or `*`, not both: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: "it is a part of the path segment of the URL" - that is correct.

Comment: But to what could it extend